# What would be the frequency of a blue light and a red light superposing?

Tags: waves

If a Blue light wave and a Red light wave move through the same point in space, would something like the beats phenomenon occur? If we were to graph the a superposed red light and green light, we'd get a function that would repeat itself after a certain interval. In sound, we call this the inverse of this interval as the beat frequency.  What frequency of light would an observer see?

Comment: What do you mean by "the beats phenomenon" here? Have you looked at [additive color mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color)?

Comment: Is there something like beats in light waves like there is in Sound waves?

Comment: That's not an explanation. A beat in acoustics is a periodic variation in volume. What do you mean by something "like" it for light?

Comment: If we were to graph the a superposed red light and green light, we'd get a function that would repeat itself after a certain interval. In sound, we call this the inverse of this interval as the beat frequency. I'm asking what frequency or color of light an observer see when looking at this superposed wave?

Comment: @ACuriousMind he's referring to what's known as "binaural beats" where two pure (sound) waves superimposed will alternately constructively and destructively interfere, forming a periodic variation in volume, and asking what visual effect superimposing two pure frequencies of light will cause.

Comment: @Asher I'm aware of what acoustic beats are, but it's not clear what their analogue for light is supposed to be. If you shine a monochromatic blue and red light together, you'll just see magenta light. Where's the "beat"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I believe that's his question, actually. Perhaps that comment could be appropriately reformatted as an answer.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for the comments. One quick question, will the magenta light have the frequency equal to the difference in frequencies of the red and blue light?

Comment: No. You will have red light and blue light still, with their frequencies unchanged. The blending to form magenta is a property of human colour vision being trichromatic, not physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind The OP is probably referring to the fact that for nearby frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$, one perceives a frequency $|f_1 - f_2|$ in the case of sound, but this is not the case for light. This is an interesting and well-formed question! The two components of the answer are: eyes have only 3 types of receptors while ears have thousands, and the response of the ear is slightly nonlinear.

Comment: @knzhou While interesting from a general perspective, I don't see how that's a physics question. The way humans perceive sound differently from light seems much more like biology.

Comment: Since beats are cycles of interference, and thus amplitude, over time, how can they 1) be dependent on biology (an observer) and 2) not be a feature of EM waves, which exhibit interference?

Comment: Acoustic beats are only observed  when the frequency bandwidth of each of the two tones is narrow compared to the frequency difference between the two tones.  Indeed, something similar happens when two lasers of different frequency are directed simultaneously onto a fast detector.  For the beat frequency to be detectable between a red laser and a blue laser though, the detector would need to be faster than any light detector I've heard of.  On the other hand, it might well be possible to convert the temporal beats to spatial beats and thereby detect them.

Comment: Also, since perceptible (to humans) beats only occur when the two frequencies are close (within 10 Hz or so?) I think red and blue are too far apart to use as a analogy. So, would two pure coherent beams of red, say 450,000,000,000,000 and 450,000,000,000,004 Hz shining at the same spot on a surface, interfere to produce a red light pulsating (brighter and dimmer) at 4 Hz, since intensity is the analogue of volume?

Comment: @S.McGrew seems like you've got a an answer there.

Comment: Google says ["optical beat interference"](https://www.google.com/search?q="optical+beat+interference") is a thing.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, Optical beat frequencies are a thing and are [useful](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/pml/div686/calibrations/OFC-2001.pdf). I don't know any application when the separation is as much as the difference between red and blue light.

Comment: The closest application I know of is "Difference Frequency Generation"  which uses optical parametric amplification to generate a light beam at the difference frequency between two light frequencies.

Comment: @Tom B., indeed, if two lasers whose output frequencies are separated by 4 Hz illuminate a photodetector simultaneously, the detector outputs a signal (not light, but current or voltage) at 4Hz.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion got a little bit off-topic.  @user190174 asked if we can ""see" the beat frequency and what color it would appear to be.  It should be pointed out that "red" and "blue" each cover a very wide frequency range.  If we re-phrase the question so it's about coherent, monochromatic light from, say, a HeNe laser and a HeCd laser, then the question becomes answerable: the beat frequency would be too low to be visible; it would be down in the infrared range.  But it would indeed exist, could be amplified (e.g., be optical parametric amplification), and could be detected with any of several kinds of detectors.